# Java can't read file while deployed on JBoss

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read a csv file, everything works before is deployed on jboss and I don't know how to solve it:
my loader is this:

```
public Map<String, String> getScript() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("scriptSQL.csv").getPath());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String arr[] = line.split(";");
        map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
    this.sqlScript = map;
    return map;
}

public String getKey(String key) {
    if (this.sqlScript != null && this.sqlScript.get(key) != null && !this.sqlScript.get(key).isEmpty()) {
        return sqlScript.get(key);
    } else {
        try {
            sqlScript = getScript();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return sqlScript.get(key);
}
```

The error when is deployed is this:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program%20Files\wildfly-18.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\archiconEar.ear\archiconWeb.war\WEB-INF\classes\scriptSQL.csv (Impossible find the path)
```

how can I say to look in the resource folder and not in this one or anything who could help me please

Comment: Don't use `File`. Just `InputStreamReader` and `getClass().getResourceAsStream`

Comment: Is file `scriptSQL.csv` inside the WAR file `archiconWeb.war`?

Answer (score 0):

Use full path to locate your file. Something like below :

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(PROJECT_PATH+"path\to\your\file\scriptSQL.csv").getPath());
```

Set PROJECT_PATH using either properties file or system variable.
E.g.

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(System.getenv("PROJECT_PATH")+"path\to\your\file\scriptSQL.csv").getPath());
```

This value will be different when you run application directly in local and when you deploy it to run in any server

Answer (score 0):

Better not to mix up your resources with your normal code packages. This uses the csv resource as placed at the root. You'd be better off creating a 'resources' directory for easier demarcation though:

```
public Map<String, String> getScript() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/scriptSQL.csv")))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String arr[] = line.split(";");
            map.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
    this.sqlScript = map;
    return map;
}
```